# Jenkins notification-poll-build fail with "No git consumers for URI ssh://path"

Tags: ssh, git, jenkins

Whenever my Jenkins gets notified about a new git commit to my repository *foo*, I get the following log/error response on the triggering client:

```
Scheduled polling of foo
No git consumers for URI ssh://git@localhost:9777/path/to/foo.git
```

This failed notification does not commence building. Using the manual "Build Now" commences building successfully.

### Setup

- I have the Jenkins instance listening on `localhost:8666`.
- I have the SSH daemon listening on `localhost:9777`.
- Within Jenkins, I have a git-based Maven project:
- - "Maven project name" is *foo*.
- - "Git Repository URL" is `ssh://git@localhost:9777/path/to/foo.git`.
- In that *bare repository*, I have a hook file `hooks/post-receive` with content:

.

```
# this is file post-receive
curl http://localhost:8666/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@localhost:9777/path/to/foo.git
```

This *building-on-commit-notification* used to work well. I have the feeling that it stopped working well once I moved from standard SSH port 22 to non-standard 9777.

What do I have to do to have a commit notification result in a successful build trigger?

---

Possibly relevant source code files:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitStatus.java
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/GitSCMSource.java

Answer (score 5):

Things to remember when connecting an hook to Jenkins:

1. Thick the `Poll SCM` option in the Build Triggers leaving the "schedule" textarea empty
2. the `url=xxx` parameter must match the "Repository URL" specified in the job configuration. If it is prefixed by ssh:// you should keep it in the notification call
3. Don't forget to `push a change to the repo` you configured! To verify you have changes:
   `http://jenkins-url:jenkins-port/job/JOB-NAME/scmPollLog/` should contain "Changes found" in the last line.

Source: [Git plugin docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository)

Comment: #3 is more important than it seems. Check that you pushed to the correct branch if your job is not configured to build every branch. At least that’s what had me searching for an error for the better part of two hours. And even though the build job is triggered successfully, I still get the “No git consumers for URI” message when pushing.

Comment: I have still some piece missing. My "http://jenkins-url:jenkins-port/job/JOB-NAME/scmPollLog/" says "Changes found", but I still get "No git jobs using repository: URL and branches:" :-(. I even installed _Poll SCM plugin_.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same thing.

The problem is that their is no change in your git since the last build. Just make some changes and then use the jenkins notify URL, it will work.

I used:

```
http://<jenkins-server_link>/git/notifyCommiturl=http://<gitrepo>.git
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the ssh:// part.

try with:

`curl http://localhost:8666/git/notifyCommit?url=git@localhost:9777/path/to/foo.git`